# Base the number format of a range of cells on a format string in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to have a format string (like '# ##0') in a cell and then base the number format of a range of other cells on the content of that cell?

I have a set of rows with dynamic formulas such that, depending on what the user selects in a drop-down list, the values should be formatted as either currency values or percentages.

If not, I will resort to VBA, but I just wanted to check if there's a VBA-less solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `TEXT()` function takes the same format string as "Format Cell" (CTRL-1) in custom (user) mode.

This would allow a cell to contain the format string, which to use when formatting a set of other cells.

say:
F1: `#.00`
A1: `=text(2*pi(),$f$1)` => `6.28`

F1: `="0.00%"`
A1 => `628.32%`

Answer (score 0):

Try using conditional formatting cell with formula depending on the value that the dropdown list returns.